# Icons for paint-like program?

Tags: icons, software-rec, microsoft-paint, image-editing

I'm looking for some simple shape icons, namely for drawing circles, rectangles, polygons and lines. 16x16. Anyone know where I can find them? I've found tons of icon sets, but these are always left out. My GIMP skills suck :(

Comment: I don't know where to find these, but if you end up needing to create them from scratch, I'd suggest a vector editor like Adobe Illustrator or maybe Inkscape rather than GIMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. http://www.iconfinder.net/ helped me get what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Try Inkscape which is directly available for Ubuntu and should feature all the icons you want.

Answer (score 2):

There's [freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org)'s icon naming specification and two well known icon sets that use it are [Tango](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) and [Oxygen](http://www.oxygen-icons.org/). They are very likely to have what you need. They also have clear licensing terms and legal paperwork, which cannot be said about most of iconfinder.net icons.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, try drawing them with paint.NET. I know you'd rather find some ready to use, but unlike GIMP (which is oriented towards manipulating existing photo images), paint.NET is actually easy to use for drawing simple shapes.

Comment: Reason I mentioned GIMP because I'm on Ubuntu and I'm too lazy to boot back into windows so I can use PS :p

Answer (score 1):

A very big legal set is downloadable as a [torrent](http://www.legaltorrents.com/torrents/340-web-development-icons-superset), more than 13.000 icons from 17 icon-sets.

Ton

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iconshock.com/icon-sets/real-vista-graphics-icons.html